# PHP: Issue with nested foreach loops

Tags: php, xpath, php-5.5

Essentially I'm attempting to pull data from several xPath queries and submit the data pulled from every file in to a row in a CSV. The problem I have is in looping through a specific xPath query and concatenating it's results in to one row.

I have the following code:

```
$category_titles = $xpath->query('//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/h1');
$category_introduction = $xpath->query('//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/p'); 

if($category_title){

  foreach($category_title){
        foreach($category_introduction as $node){
            $test .= $node->nodeValue;
            var_dump($test);
            continue();
         }  

            $test = '':
     }  
}
```

I'm attempting to loop the `$category_introduction` query for each `$category_title` and concatenate each `<p>` element. I'm then attempting to break out of the loop when all `<p>` tags have been concatenated and repeat the process only with `$test` cleared. Could anyone suggest how I might do this in a nested foreach loop? I've never written a nested loop and am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is with if condition and foreach loop because in if condition and foreach loop you have declared wrong variable

Try this

```
if($category_titles)
```

and

```
foreach($category_titles)
```

Instead of

```
if($category_title)
```

and

```
foreach($category_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Umesh Chauhans answer.

I see several problems with your code:

1. $test is not initialized.
2. The if($category_title) only checks for the values existence. Not for it to be iterable. You might want to use is_array().
3. Your first foreach loop does not use the item to be iterated (the as $value part is missing). 
   See PHP doc: foreach (array_expression as $value) statement;
4. continue is a keyword not a function, so omit the (), look up the PHP doc as well

In general you might want to query $xpath->query('//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div'); and then do subqueries.